# How correctly update Flow?

Tags: flowtype

updated flow-bin with `yarn global add flow-bin@latest`. `yarn global ls` shows **"flow-bin@0.38.0"**. `flow version` shows **Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.37.4**. How update flow to latest version?

OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Yarn: latest

P.S. I also did reboot several times...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

1. Check where is flow - `whereis flow`
2. Remove it - `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/flow`
3. Add Flow - `yarn global add flow-bin@latest`

I don't remember if I installed Flow with NPM or no, even after deleting whole Node.js and NPM and reinstalling, it was always 0.37.4 version, but after that fix everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same for **Mac OS (Catalina)**

1. Check where is flow - which flow
2. Remove it - sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/flow
3. Add Flow - yarn global add flow-bin@latest

Within my project (react-native) I had to match the target version of the **.flowconfig-file** to the corresponding version I get from *flow version* in Terminal.